# How to implement a Classification Problem in Deep Learning for an EEG application?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, signal-processing

I am new to this and would like to know how should I implement a classification problem for my EEG application. I did some digging and found that the traditional machine learning methods based on EEG signal always consider the features of the time-domain and/or frequency-domain. Similarly, I have the frequency domain (i.e. power spectral density) data which I am going to use as features.
I am willing to use CNN architecture for this Neural Network with the Tensorflow library. Am I Thinking straight with this one? I need to know where should I start with, though I have gone through some deep learning courses and Textbooks.
Additionally, according to previous researches, convert EEG signals to 2D EEG images with Azimuthal Equidistant Projection (AEP) technique. Is it mandatory to do this, can't we just convert the EEG signals (2D matrix) (csv file) to an image file? Can't we use the matrix as it is and changing it to an image?

Comment: Hey, Yash. Converting time-series data to a spectogram or another kind of matrix and applying a CNN is a common thing. But you could also keep it as time-series data and apply a recurrent neural network (RNN/LSTM/GRU)

Comment: Hi, @Theodor. Thanks for the suggestion. 
From the literature, it seems that most people have used CNN architecture for the same, that's why I started from this.
Is it necessary/mandatory to use the Azimuthal Equidistant Projection technique, can't we just covert it to an image (RGB) by using any available sw?